# Converting dynamic JSON in flutter to models

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, dynamic

Converting a JSON to model would be a straight forward process. Let's consider a simple JOSON string as seen below;

```
jsonData ={'id':'1','name':'modelItem'}
```

It can be converted to model using below model class.

```
class Model{

final String? id;
final String? name;

Model({this.id,this.name});
}
```

But what about below JSON string?

```
jsonData= {'NYC':{'city code':'NYC','country code':'US'}}
```

Or another string like below?

```
jsondata= {'NYC': {'NYC':'NEW YORK'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following is the solution for converting first JSON string

```
jsonData= {
           'NYC':{'cityCode':'NYC','countryCode':'US'},
           'SYD':{'cityCode':'SYD','countryCode':'AU'}              
          }
```

Solution for `jsonData= {'NYC':{'city code':'NYC','country code':'US'}}`

No matter how nested the JSON string data is, create a model class to convert inner map first. And then, try to work on the outer layer and so on.

```
class CityDetails{
final String? cityCode;
final String? countryCode;
CityDetails({this. cityCode, this. countryCode});

CityDetails.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson) {
   for(var element in parsedJson.entries){
     CityDetails(cityCode:element.key, countryCode:element.value);
   }
 }
}
```

Now, let's work on the outer layer which should give a list of `CityDetails`. Same method can be applied. However, here city code is repeated in the outer layer and it can be ignored. So the result should look like a `List<CityDetails>`.

```
class CityDataList{
 final List<CityDetails> cityDetailsList;
 CityDataList({this.cityDetailsList});

 factory CityDataList.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson){
   List<CityDetails> cityDetailsList=[];

   for(var element in parsedJson.entries){   
       cityDetailsList.add(CityDetails(cityCode:element.key,
      countryCode:element.value));
   }

 return CityDataList(cityDetailsList: cityDetailsList);
 }

}
```

Solution for `jsondata= {'NYC': {'NYC':'NEW YORK'}}`. Solution for first problem would help to convert the outer JSON here, so it is not repeated here. Following helps to convert the inner JSON into a meaningful class.

```
class CityData{
 final String? cityCode;
 final String? cityName;

 CityData({this.cityCode,this.cityName});
 
 CityData.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson){
  for(each element in parsedJson.entries){
     CityData(citycode:element.key,cityName:element.value);
  }
 }
}
```